# How to tell the context an Xpage is running in - Sidebar

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpage that I want to put in a panel in the sidebar.

I only want the entry part to be in the panel, so I made a ccEntry Custom Control and I put it into an Xpage for the main app and into an Xpage that is for the widget and ONLY contains the ccEntry form.

When I run the widget in the sidebar and hit submit, the code in the submit (which says previous) goes to the entire page. I want to put something in the button to like if I am in a sidebar then do this else do this. So if I could grab the name of the Xpage in a field that would do, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try view.getPageName(). That will give you a string of the current XPage's name in the format "/somepage.xsp".

Comment: That works great. Would this be the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: I thought about that a bit and I don't think there's anything terribly wrong with it. It might be a bit cleaner to add a property to the custom control to specify the post-submit destination page, so that it's a bit more clear what's going on. The "proper" JSF route would be to work this out with navigation rules, but they're not necessary if you haven't delved into them before.

Answer (score 0):

@Jesse's solution makes something nasty: the control gets tightly coupled to its surroundings. You have two options:

### Redirect

Define custom control's parameter with page name or URL to redirect to. Your submit button then redirects to that URL (accessed by `compositeData.param`). Your pages define different parameter value.

### Navigation (preferred)

Your submit button's last command is simple line of code:

```
return "submitted";
```

Your pages for app/sidebar define different [navigation rule](http://xpagetips.blogspot.sk/2012/08/navigation-rules-need-to-go-somewhere.html) target for the same rule: "submitted".